# Create tiles effect on web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to create tiles effect like [here](https://www.obbserv.com/)?

Also, when any tile is clicked, two sections appear. One from right, another from left side and overlays landing page. How to do similar effect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The page you linked to uses [Isotope.js](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/).
You could also use [Masonry.js](https://masonry.desandro.com/), which is similar.

Comment: Thanks for response Chase. But, both suggestion solves first ask.

How does the second part works?

Comment: That is a completely different question.